# What is the "full unit" of the native coin (HBAR) on Hedera?

Tags: solidity, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

In my smart contract, I would like to accept exactly 1 full HBAR unit in a payable function.
The following code would work in Ethereum, by specifying `1 ether`.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract Example {
    function payMeOneHbar () public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether, "Payment required is exactly 1 HBAR");
        /* ... other code */
    }
}
```

Does Hedera have the equivalent concept to `1 ether`?
(I cannot specify `1 hbar` in Solidity, as that isn't recognised by `solc`.)

I tried accepting `1 HBAR` and expected it would have the same function as `1 ether`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify `100_000_000` or `10^8` in place of  `1 ether`, like so:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract Example {
    function payMeOneHbar () public payable {
        require(msg.value == 100_000_000, "Payment required is exactly 1 HBAR");
        /* ... other code */
    }
}
```

Note that the absolute numerical value is different from that on Ethereum.

---

***Detailed explanation***

In Solidity syntax, `ether` is simply a constant that is equal to `10^18` (`1,000,000,000,000,000,000`).
Ref: [Solidity Lang - Ether Units](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units)

> - 1 wei = 1 wei
> - 1 gwei = 1,000,000,000 wei
> - 1 ether = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 wei

In Solidity syntax there is no concept of `hbar`, but we can use a constant value of `10^8` (`100,000,000`) in its place.
Ref: [Hedera - HBAR](https://hedera.com/hbar#:%7E:text=What%20are%20the%20official%20HBAR%20cryptocurrency%20denominations) and [Hedera Helpdesk - What are the official HBAR cryptocurrency denominations?](https://help.hedera.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000674317-What-are-the-official-HBAR-cryptocurrency-denominations-)

> - 1 Gℏ = 1,000,000,000 ℏ
> - 1 Mℏ = 1,000,000 ℏ
> - 1Kℏ = 1,000 ℏ
> - 1 ℏ = 1 ℏ
> - 1,000 mℏ = 1 ℏ
> - 1,000,000 μℏ = 1 ℏ
> - 100,000,000 tℏ = 1 ℏ

**Try it out**

You can try this out manually using the following Solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract NativeCoinUnits {
    // for ethereum,
    // - the "full unit" of the native coin is an ether, and
    // - the "smallest unit" is a wei
    uint256 public oneWei = 1 wei;
    bool public isOneWei = (oneWei == 1);
    uint256 public oneEther = 1 ether;
    bool public isOneEther = (oneEther == 1e18);

    // for hedera,
    // - the "full unit" of the native coin is an hbar, and
    // - the "smallest unit" is a tinyhbar
    uint256 public oneTinybar = 1;
    bool public isOneTinybar = (oneTinybar == 1);
    uint256 public oneHbar = 100_000_000; // note specify manually, no unit
    bool public isOneHbar = (oneHbar == 1e8);
}
```

Hot link to [try this out in Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/?#code=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)

... and if you deploy it, and invoke each of the auto-generated getter functions, you should get this result:

[image: Remix IDE getter invocation results for the NativeCoinUnits smart contract]

As you can see, all of the `isOne...` boolean values are `true`;
and all the `one...` unsigned integer values are equal to the constants from the reference values copied above.

Answer (score 1):

In my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76125162/194982),
I realised that I used a bit of circuitous logic.

After reading [HIP-410: Wrapping Ethereum Transaction Bytes in a Hedera Transaction](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-improvement-proposal/blob/master/HIP/hip-410.md) ,
there is a section which defines a new concept called **weibars**:
["Value of gas price and value fields"](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-410#value-of-gas-price-and-value-fields)

> For Ethereum transactions, we introduce the concept of “WeiBars”, which are 1 to 10^-18th the value of a HBAR.
> This is to maximize compatibility with third party tools that expect ether units to be operated on in fractions of 10^18,
> also known as a Wei.
> Thus, 1 tinyBar is 10^10 weiBars or 10 gWei.

... it was imperative to "prove" whether the smallest unit
used in Solidity smart contracts deployed to Hedera
was a **tinybar** or a **weibar**.

To do this, I configured MetaMask to connect to Hedera Testnet
(via `hedera-json-rpc-relay`),
and used Remix to deploy the following smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract TinybarsDemo {
    function checkBalance()
        public view
        returns (uint256 senderBalance)
    {
        senderBalance = msg.sender.balance;
    }
}
```

You can [try this out on Remix yourself](https://remix.ethereum.org/?#code=Ly8gU1BEWC1MaWNlbnNlLUlkZW50aWZpZXI6IEdQTC0zLjAKcHJhZ21hIHNvbGlkaXR5IDAuOC4xODsKCmNvbnRyYWN0IFRpbnliYXJzRGVtbyB7CiAgICBmdW5jdGlvbiBjaGVja0JhbGFuY2UoKQogICAgICAgIHB1YmxpYyB2aWV3CiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJucyAodWludDI1NiBzZW5kZXJCYWxhbmNlKQogICAgewogICAgICAgIHNlbmRlckJhbGFuY2UgPSBtc2cuc2VuZGVyLmJhbGFuY2U7CiAgICB9Cn0K).

After deployment:

- In the wallet, I have a balance of approximately `104` HBAR
- This is approximately `10400000000` tinybar (`104` followed by **8** digits)
- This is approximately `104000000000000000000` weibar (`104` followed by **18** digits)

[image: tinybars-or-weibars-metamask-balance]

When I invoke the `checkBalance` function on the smart contract -
which simply returns `msg.sender.balance` -
it responded with `10432200425`.

[image: tinybars-or-weibars-remix-checkbalance-senderbalance]

Since `10432200425` is `104` followed by **8** digits
(and not **18** digits),
we can confirm that the smallest unit used is indeed **tinybar**
(and not **weibar**).